# MATLAB: Adding a bar graph to plotyy messes up line plot

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, line-plot

I am using plotyy() to plot both precipitation data (bar plot) and flow data (line plot). When I add both datasets as line plots, everything looks fine (top image, see link). When I add the precipitation data as a bar plot, it messes up the smoothness of the line plot (bottom image, see link). I do not have this issue with all of my datasets, but two are giving me this problem. I have tried loading the data from a different source and plotting the data individually. The bar plot always messes up my line plot. I cannot figure out what might be causing this. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Files for Minimum Example

[Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwY3q-GrOctYdW1Zd2VNVG51ZTg)

[Matlab File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwY3q-GrOctYSjB1SHNuMHRsbWM)

[image: Click here to see figures]

Comment: Can you try to create a [mcve], emphasis on **minimum**

Comment: Can you include the mat file with some test `Date`, `Precip`, `M1`, `M2`, `M3` and `M4` too?

Comment: I added a simplified MATLAB file and dataset for testing the problem. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: When I was testing for a minimal example, I noticed that the issue only occurs once the 601st data point is added, regardless of its location within the dataset.

Comment: I am unable to recreate the error in your example, even when I add data points

Comment: I was wondering if that might happen. The error is just too weird. I am running MATLAB R2014a. Perhaps something about my machine is causing the problem. Thanks for testing it.

Comment: Could be it.`yyaxis()` replaced `plotyy()` in 2016a

Answer (score 0):

I copied the figure and pasted it into a Word document. As ridiculous as this sounds, it looks perfectly normal in the Word document but is still messed up in the MATLAB figure window and in the .png I saved. The error is definitely caused by a bug. At least I know to try pasting the figure into Word first next time.

Thanks to everyone who read through my question and provided feedback.